# Adding a fade-in effect to submenu using CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, animate.css

I have a simple question. I am trying to add a fade-in effect to the submenus like in [this page](http://www.web2feel.com/working-with-css-drop-down-menus-and-animate-css/) but I don't really understand the `ul li ul` selectors concept well and so it is not coming out correct.,

It doesn't seem really difficult but I am doing something wrong which I can't figure out!!

How can I add this CSS transition effect? I have tried using the animate.css library but usage of the library is not mandatory and I am OK with a solution which doesn't use it also.

```
.classname li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
  -moz-animation: fadeInUp .3s ease-in  ;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInUp .3s ease-in ;
  animation:fadeInUp .3s ease-in ;
}

.classname ul li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
  -moz-animation: fadeInRight .3s ease-in ;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .3s ease-in ;
  animation:fadeInRight .3s ease-in ;
}
```

**Demo:** Below is a snippet which has my current coding attempt.

```css
/* MENU NAVIGATION */

#nav span {
  display: none;
}
#nav,
#nav ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
}
#nav ul.subs {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #333333;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  width: 96%;
}
#nav > li {
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
  white-space: normal;
}
#nav > li > a {
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav > li:hover > a,
#nav > a:hover {
  background-color: #F55856;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav li.active > a {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
/* submenu */

#nav li:hover ul.subs {
  display: block;
}
#nav ul.subs > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding: 10px 1%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33%;
}
#nav ul.subs > li a {
  color: #777777;
  line-height: 20px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #F55856;
}
#nav ul.subs > li > a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav ul.subs > li li {
  float: none;
  padding-left: 8px;
  -moz-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
  -o-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
  transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
}
#nav ul.subs > li li:hover {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#s1">Prodotti</a>
      <span id="s1"></span>
      <ul class="subs">
        <li><a href="#">Header a</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Header b</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Area Privata</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contatti</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Harry , what I'm trying to do is to add an animation to the submenu on mouse over, I'm try to use one of this https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: But I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is the right way. could U help me?!

Comment: without using the library i could be ok, the important thing is to understand WHERE i have to put the correct information in css, what I'm trying to do is something like this http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/css-menu/index.html  .... the animation must be on submenu if is possible ( the second level )

Comment: this is the previous page, ( http://www.web2feel.com/working-with-css-drop-down-menus-and-animate-css/ ) he use a "fadeinup" animation from animate.css ... the animation must be on hovering PRODOTTI on the sub menu.

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bka96jhm/) what you need? There is a fadeInUp animation on hovering the PRODOTTI and a fadeInRight animation on hovering the Header 1 and Header 2 (like in the page you had linked).

Comment: yeah!!!!! thanksssssssssss how can i understand it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for an animation or a separate library to achieve the effect that you need. These can be achieved by just using transitions and some CSS transforms.

**Demo:** (explanation is provided below).

```css
/* MENU NAVIGATION */

#nav span {
  display: none;
}
#nav,
#nav ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
}
#nav ul.subs {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #333333;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  width: 96%;
}
#nav > li {
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 450ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 450ms ease-in-out 0s;
  white-space: normal;
}
#nav > li > a {
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav > li:hover > a,
#nav > a:hover {
  background-color: #F55856;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav li.active > a {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
/* submenu */

#nav ul.subs > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding: 10px 1%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33%;
}
#nav ul.subs > li a {
  color: #777777;
  line-height: 20px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #F55856;
}
#nav ul.subs > li > a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav ul.subs > li li {
  float: none;
  padding-left: 8px;
  transition: padding 150ms ease-out 0s;
}
#nav ul.subs > li li:hover {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
#nav > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#nav > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  pointer-events: auto;
}
#nav > li > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  transition: all 150ms ease;
}
#nav > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#s1">Prodotti</a>
      <span id="s1"></span>
      <ul class="subs">
        <li><a href="#">Header a</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Header b</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu z</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Area Privata</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contatti</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Code Explained:**

In order to produce an effect similar to that in the page which you linked (that is, the 1st level submenu does a fade-in + move up on hover and the 2nd level sub-menu does a fade-in + move left on hover), the following things need to be done:

- Currently you are toggling the `display` property of the `ul` that contains the first level submenu when hovering on PRODOTTI. But change of value to the `display` property is not transitionable and because of this the submenu will appear in an instant. Just remove the lines that cause this.

```
#nav ul.subs {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #333333;
    /*display: none; comment out or remove this line */
    left: 0;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    width: 96%;
}
/* remove these */
#nav li:hover ul.subs {
  display: block;
}
```

- After that set the initial state of the `ul` that contains the submenu to have `opacity: 1` and also add `transform: translateY(25%)` to it. This will push the submenu's container down by 25% of its height.

```
#nav > li > ul{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

- When the PRODOTTI link is hovered, change the submenu's `opacity` to 1 and translate it back to its original position by setting `transform: translateY(0%). This makes it look as though the submenu is fading-in and is moving up at the same time.

```
#nav > li:hover > ul{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

- For the second level submenu, the same steps are followed except that instead of using `translateY`, we are using `translateX` because it has to be moved to the right and not down.

```
#nav > li > ul > li > ul{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  transition: all 150ms ease;
}
#nav > li > ul > li:hover > ul{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```